# How can I implement csrf attack implimentation on my gcp functions

Tags: node.js, security, google-cloud-platform, oauth, csrf

I am have created the gcp functions (developed using Node.js) which are secured with Oauth token as of now, on top of it I want to protect my functions from XSS and CSRF attacks.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

There are some basic guidelines that you are to follow in order to prevent XSS or CSRF attacks, however, they are mostly on the side of your code.

I would recommend you to take a look as [this document](https://www.google.com/about/appsecurity/learning/xss/#PreventingXSS) which explains a bit on how to prevent XSS attacks and [this one](https://owasp.org/www-project-cheat-sheets/cheatsheets/Nodejs_security_cheat_sheet.html) for CSRF.

Hope you find this information useful.